# JBoss Beans @Inject throwing a null exception

Tags: java, jboss, resteasy

I have a bean which is injected in a class which is throwing a null pointer exception.

exception

```
org.jboss.resteasy.spi.UnhandledException: java.lang.NullPointerException
    org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.handleApplicationException(SynchronousDispatcher.java:340)
    org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.handleException(SynchronousDispatcher.java:214)
    org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.handleInvokerException(SynchronousDispatcher.java:190)
    org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.getResponse(SynchronousDispatcher.java:540)
    org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invoke(SynchronousDispatcher.java:502)
    org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invoke(SynchronousDispatcher.java:119)
    org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.ServletContainerDispatcher.service(ServletContainerDispatcher.java:208)
    org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher.service(HttpServletDispatcher.java:55)
    org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher.service(HttpServletDispatcher.java:50)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:847)
```

---

The funny thing is that the same code works on another computer. But same settings and same code. Can anyone help out?

---

Edit

code:

@Inject private NameBean nameBean;

```
@GET
@Produces("application/json")
@Path("/abc")
public String getname() {
    return nameBean.getName().toJSON().toString();
}
```

---

JBoss Version 7.1.1

---

OS Windows 7

Comment: code, jboss version, ejb version, OS?